# Can mesh from CAD model be overwritten

Tags: mesh

I have problems with complex mesh on CAD models, I found out that mesh chace displays different mesh in object mode, how can I apply it so I could see it in edit mode also?
[image: Complex mesh]
[image: Simple mesh]
Green picture is what I wont. 
I dont wont to make animations, just simplefied object with texture ready for export but complex suface mesh gives me headache with UV maps and everything...
Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're in wireframe view. The faces and edges you see in edit mode, are still there in object mode as well, but for some reeason wireframe view sometimes doesn't show some edges (I don't really know why, but perhaps someone else can shed some light on this). Press Z on your keyboard to toggle between wireframe and solid view.

Comment: Short answer is you can't, at least not in an easy one-button-press way. What you are seeing in object mode is just a viewport simplification, all those edges are still there. You can either try a remesh modifier or Tris to quads in edit mode, but don't expect a miracle

Comment: @duane-dibbley in object mode Blender tries to simply geometry for performance and clarity reasons, edges between two faces below a certain angle register as a flat surface or smooth curved, so no edge is drawn between them

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the explanation.